# Consumir Web services desde Android Studio

Tags: android, web, wcf, studio

quería saber si alguien tiene un tutorial de como consumir un web services desde android studio, muchas gracias, ya que llevo rato intentándolo con KSOAP2 y no me funciona.

En los datos del web service los seteo de esta manera

El codigo que estoy utilizado es el siguiente:

```
    public static String Registro() {
    String responce = null;

    final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    final String URL="http://192.168.0.112/WSConsultaAD.asmx";
    final String METHOD_NAME = "LogueoAD";
    final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/LogueoAD";


    PropertyInfo user = new PropertyInfo();
    PropertyInfo pass = new PropertyInfo();

    user.setName("user");
    user.setValue("admin");
    pass.setName("pass");
    pass.setValue("123");




    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,  METHOD_NAME);


    request.addProperty(user);
    request.addProperty(pass);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);//AQUI ESTA EL PROBLEMA
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE aht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    try {
        aht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        SoapPrimitive LoginResult;
        LoginResult = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
        System.out.println("=================Register User Results: "+LoginResult.toString());
        //System.out.println(LoginResult.toString());
        responce = LoginResult.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }




    return responce;
}
```

En este código le estoy seteando el usuario directamente para hacer la prueba, lo que sucede es que cuando llega al punto de

```
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);//AQUI ESTA EL PROBLEMA
```

Se cae, el web service funciona correctamente, es a la hora de consumirlo en el android studio.

Gracias de antemano, saludos!

**El error que da el logcat es el siguiente**

```
2020-08-04 15:48:32.195 11564-11564/? E/com.example.ar: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2020-08-04 15:48:37.992 11564-12278/com.example.ari E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
2020-08-04 15:48:37.992 11564-12278/com.example.ari E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
2020-08-04 15:48:46.503 11564-11564/com.example.ari E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.ari, PID: 11564
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/kxml2/io/KXmlSerializer;
    at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.createRequestData(Transport.java:80)
    at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:79)
    at com.example.ari.Tarea.Registro(Tarea.java:119)
    at com.example.ari.LogueoActivity$1.onClick(LogueoActivity.java:46)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102)
    at android.view.View.access$3400(View.java:801)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27301)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7319)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:934)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.kxml2.io.KXmlSerializer" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.ari-JDJTt5YdGkVhLATulNWvIw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.ari-JDJTt5YdGkVhLATulNWvIw==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system/product/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:196)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.createRequestData(Transport.java:80) 
    at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:79) 
    at com.example.ari.Tarea.Registro(Tarea.java:119) 
    at com.example.ari.LogueoActivity$1.onClick(LogueoActivity.java:46) 
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125) 
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102) 
    at android.view.View.access$3400(View.java:801) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27301) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7319) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:934)
```

**SOLUCIÓN
Descargue la última versión del KSOAP del siguiente enlace:**

https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/ksoap2-android-releases/com/google/code/ksoap2-android/ksoap2-android-assembly/3.4.0/

Comment: Bienvenido, que es lo que no funciona? agrega mas detalles del problema que presentaste por favor.

Comment: Ahí actualice el código, gracias de antemano!

Comment: excelente muchas gracias, en el LogCat que error se muestra ?

Comment: Ahí agregue el error que me da el logcat, gracias !

Comment: El error es claro. No encuentra la clase `KXmlSerializer` si vas a usarla tienes que importarla donde uses código relativo a esa clase.

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias ya lo resolvi lo que hice fue actualizar el KSOAP  a la última versión y se me resolvió el problema, lo descargue de aquí por si alguien tiene el mismo problema. https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/ksoap2-android-releases/com/google/code/ksoap2-android/ksoap2-android-assembly/3.4.0/